# java. Почему метод, создающий пустой .txt не работает без обработчика исключений?

Tags: java, исключения

Почему метод, создающий файл (пустой .txt) не работает без обработчика исключений?

```
package filecreator;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileName = "My File.txt";
        String filePath = "/Users/Donrumata/Desktop/";

        File myFile = new File(filePath + "/" + fileName);

        try {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

В этом случае компиляция проходит без ошибок (если я не ошибаюсь), но без обработчика - именно в строке с методом, создающим файл, происходит IOExeption. Почему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дело в том, что сигнатура метода [содержит](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()) ключевое слово `throws`, кое означает, что вызов метода может выкинуть ошибку типа `IOException`.

Методы, так обозначенные не могут быть вызваны вне обработчика исключений (try/catch) или метода, с подобной же сигнатурой.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Изучаю Java с нуля, появляется много "банальных" вопросов)...

Comment: @MaximVelichkin, если один из ответов отвечает на ваш вопрос, то вы можете отметить его "верным", нажав на галочку слева от отела ответа)

Comment: Оба ответа отвечают и очень помогли мне, отмечаю первый по порядку, всем огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Потому что метод `createNewFile()` выглядит вот так:

```
public boolean createNewFile() throws java.io.IOException;
```

`throws` указывает, что метод может при определенных условия выкинуть `IOException`, а вызов методов с throws без обертки в `try-catch` невозможен, оттуда и ошибка.

**UPD:**
Невозможен, если метод, вызывающий другой метод, имеющий `throws`, не содержит `throws`

**По твоему примеру:** Если приписать твоему методу `main` ключевое слово `throws`, то ты можешь забыть про использование `try-catch`, однако по отношению к `main` я не стал бы так делать.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String fileName = "My File.txt";
    String filePath = "/Users/Donrumata/Desktop/";

    File myFile = new File(filePath + "/" + fileName);

    try {
        myFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Можно без try-catch, если вызвать в методе с подобной же сигнатурой)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну, в приведенном автором методе невозможно

Comment: Я ни разу не пробовал, но, вот по [ссылке](https://habrahabr.ru/company/golovachcourses/blog/225585/) есть пример `public static void main` со словом `throws`. Так что, думаю, есть вероятность того, что прописав это в сигнатуру `main` метода всё скомпилируется)

Comment: @dDevil можно вроде бы. Тогда ошибки будет JVM обрабатывать. И ругаться матом)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб скомпилится 100. также могу поспорить, что я где-то видел, что ide автоматом генерит main с подобной сигнатурой по дефолту, не netbeans точно. хотя, я думаю, все это можно настроить под себя. хотя вероятно, вы меня неправильно поняли, я имел ввиду, что невозможно без try-catch, так как данный main не имеет throws

Comment: @dDevil, а тогда вопросов нет, но, кмк, лучше будет, если вы это в ответе помянете)

Comment: Спасибо! Я встречал где-то такую конструкцию, когда main  добавляли throws Exception, но тогда не понял что это, теперь становится понятно. А в чем недостатки этого способа?

Comment: @MaximVelichkin ты не пойми неправильно. это довольно полезная фишка, но думаю, в main она неуместно, так как я думаю, что в точке запуска все исключения должны быть обязательно обработаны перед стартом и ничего не выкинуто вне. опять же обработчик исключений нужно ставить там, где это нужно, а не в каждой строчке;) а вообще, все приживется со временем и практикой

Comment: Буду иметь в виду, спасибо!